# GPS track smoothing in R

Tags: r, gps, smoothing

I know there are several posts about this, but I could not find exactly what I need. I have GPS track data (from an underwater vehicle) for short intervals of 1 second (time-stamps on data). The data are noisy and especially when the vehicle stops the track becomes messy. I'd like to smooth the track to calculate a realistic travelled length of the track(in the way it is described here https://www.gpsvisualizer.com/tutorials/track_filters.html), ideally implementing in R.

I have tried the RDP: The Ramer-Douglas-Peucker Algorithm function, but this does either totally oversmooth or keep those areas where the vehicle stops and there are dense data.

Comment: If you are looking for statistical advice on what sort of model would be appropriate to smooth this data, your question would be a better fit at stats.stackexchange.com. If you are looking help coding the algorithm at you link, please share a reproducible example including sample data in a copy/pasteable format and code from your best attempt. `dput()` is the nicest way to share sample data. `dput(your_data[1:20, ])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 20 rows of `your_data` including all data structure information.

Comment: Thanks Gregor - I think I'll be posting this at stats - sorry I am new to stackoverflow and not sure how the organisation of forums work

Comment: No worries! Welcome to the site, and we hope to see you back when you have a fitting question :) (Please bring reproducible data to your R questions!)